# He looks like he just got out of famine

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction, sentence-structure, sentence-choice

In Urdu language, there is a saying which is used to describe a person who eats so fast and too much humorously or sarcastically (depending on the context its connotation can vary.) They say:

> Look at the way he eats. **He looks like *he* just got out of a famine**. *(Literal translation.)*

**Meaning:** As if he has been hungry for a long time and has been starving recently.

I was wondering if it makes sense in English to use "famine" in this case metaphorically? 
Meanwhile, I have my doubts how it would be better-sounding!

> - **He looks like he** just got out of a famine.
> - **He looks (as if / as though) he** just got out of a famine.
> - **It looks (as if / as though) he** just got out of famine.

Please kindly enlighten me.

Comment: The equivalent idiom in English is "He looks like he hasn't eaten for a week," or better still "You would think he hadn't eaten for a week."

Comment: I wonder how can I use the word "famine" in this sense @KateBunting in a way it sounds idiomatic and natural?

Comment: or *looks like he's **literally starving***. Native Anglophones wouldn't use "famine" in this casually metaphoric sense, probably because culturally speaking we're not really closely associated with famine. What you *will* sometimes hear, even today, is things like [*He looked like he just got out of Auschwitz*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22he+just+got+out+of+auschwitz%22) (or *Belsen*, Nazi concentration camp victims were often horrifically emaciated). But you probably shouldn't copy that one either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the word famine in this sense, not even hyperbolically.

You can say "He looks like he hasn't eaten for a week" or "He must have been starving!" (as suggested by comments)

Never use "like he just got out of Auschwitz".  That's about as bad as casually use the "N" word.

Comment: Well, then how about the following constructions @James K. : "**He looks (as if / as though) he hasn't eaten for a week**" OR "**It looks (as if / as though) he hasn't eaten for a week**" IS it an idiomatic one?

Comment: _It looks as though_ suggests that you seriously think it may be the case, which presumably is not the intention.